# Android x86-based system image not found in SDK rev 18 update

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator, x86, intel

Yesterday I've updated Android SDK to rev 18, but there's only ARM EABI v7a system image for API level 14 & 15, while in [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm) they say I could use x86-based system image for better & smoother performance of emulator. I've check in sdk-folder\tool\ and "emulator-86.exe" also exists, but no x86 AVD created to run with this. I also install HAXM and it works fine in my machine. In GUI AVD creation, the CPU/ABI dropdown box also be disabled for every API level.

So where I could find and use x86 based system image for my Android SDK? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can also download images for use with HAXM and the emulator direct from [Intel's website](http://software.intel.com/en-us/android/).  The current one at [this link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/android-44-kitkat-x86-emulator-system-image) is API 19 (4.4).

Answer (score 0):

15 is the current top API level. Only the SDK Tools and the plugin have a revision level of 18. In Windows systems you will find your AVDs below: **\users\you\.android\avd**

Comment: Yeah i know it, but i'm asking where i could find x86 based system image to create cpu emulator instead of default arm-abi emulator???

Comment: The highest Intel Atom x86 system image is API level 10, which you can see when you open the SDK Manager and look at what's installed and what's available.

Comment: Oh, thanks so much. I got it. I misunderstood the GPU accelerated (which only available for API level 15) and CPU emulation (which available for API level 10)